# Ingenuity Three Axis Velocity Derivation from Camera, Gyro and Altimeter

Tags: velocity, sensors, ingenuity

It seems that Ingenuity has a 4000 pixel camera, a gyro, inclinometer and an altimeter. Using these information, they are able to derive three axis velocity information. Thereby compensating for the inability to put a doppler velocity instrument.

In Page 11 of [Mars Helicopter Technology Demonstrator](https://trs.jpl.nasa.gov/bitstream/handle/2014/46229/CL%2317-6243.pdf) (also here [1](https://rotorcraft.arc.nasa.gov/Publications/files/Balaram_AIAA2018_0023.pdf), [2](https://web.archive.org/web/20190401121747/https://rotorcraft.arc.nasa.gov/Publications/files/Balaram_AIAA2018_0023.pdf)):

> This processor implements visual navigation via a velocity estimate derived from features tracked in the VGA camera, filter propagation for use in flight control, data management, command processing, telemetry generation, and radio communication.

I have two questions basically,

1. How are they able to do that? I am looking for the algorithm/equations used. Are they looking at pixel shift or some [ML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) algorithm is implemented?
2. What are the accuracies compared the traditional doppler velocity instruments in landers at the height where ingenuity will operate.

Comment: great question!!

Comment: @Prakhar This doesn't answer your question at all, but there's a little discussion about 8 mins in: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhsZUZmJvaM

Comment: Optical flow is supposed to be pretty simple.

Comment: @ikrase. Yeah but then there is this problem if being inclined and separating motion due to rates and actual velocity.. It isnt as trivial as far as I think. Cant think its even analytical solvable

Comment: If they have a good IMU, three axis rotational velocity information and two axis attitude is fairly trivial. Does it really not have an accelerometer?

Comment: It has MEMS gyro. Yeah Its trivial if you assume rate info to be precise and attitude to be precise. But it should be some sort of KF estimation I guess.

Comment: "A few dozen features are compared frame to frame to track relative position to figure out direction and speed, " https://spectrum.ieee.org/automation/aerospace/robotic-exploration/nasa-designed-perseverance-helicopter-rover-fly-autonomously-mars

Comment: That is a good read @Cornelisinspace